# Prove that there are infinitely many values of $n$ for which $\phi(n)=\frac{n}{2}-1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that $\phi(n)=\frac{n}{2}-1$ is actually one of the strong lines on a plot of Euler's phi function, the other being $\phi(n)=n-1$. However I don't know how to go about proving it. Where should I start? Thanks.

Comment: Consider $n=2p$ for prime $p(p\neq2) $ and apply the formula of function.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If $p > 2$ is a prime, then $\varphi(2p) = p-1$.

Comment: Ok, so I've understood that φ(2p)=φ(2^1*p^1)=φ(2)*φ(p)=1*(p^1-1)=p-1. But I'm not sure how this helps me prove the statement?

Comment: If you set $n = 2p$ for some prime $p > 2$, then what can you say about $\varphi(n)$?

Comment: It's equal to p-1. And therefore there will always be p-1 amount of numbers?

Comment: Try expressing that in terms of $n$.